# Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebStress.WebTestSuite

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

I am looking for this object:

Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebStress.WebTestSuite

I can't seem to find it anywhere.

I am working in the VS2012 SDK and I know this object does exist because it is used internally.

I have looked all over the web for information on this, but there is none.

Thanks ahead.

Comment: Where have you seen references to that namespace (ie Why do you want it?) I also can't find a reference from a quick Google but there may be another way to solve your issue

Comment: is it part of ultimate?

Answer (score 0):

This is only part of the Enterprise Version of Visual Studio (2015 onwards).